# Looptools missing blender 2.8

Tags: modeling

Where are the loop tools in blender 2.8? I seem to have them enabled but can't hotkey; selecting 
edges and pressing "W" does not bring them up.

[image]

Comment: Go to the edit subpanel on the right of the viewport

Comment: Where? (How?) exactly? I've tried all  "check" combos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry, it's still there.

- Context menu is available through <kbd>Right Click.</kbd>
- Operations are (hidden) under the *Edit tab*
  (the name can be changed in *Preferences > Addons > LoopTools*)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Found it. Pretty obscure though.

Comment: You're right :). No idea why the tab isn't labeled *LoopTools* by default.

Comment: Expanding on this answer to make it more clear: LoopTools will ONLY show up when you are in Edit Mode. Then it will appear in the side menu thingy (press N).